# Image looks fine in Microsoft Edge, but not right in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am new to html and css. I am building my own website [upsites.co.za](https://upsites.co.za)

If you open up the home page on Google Chrome, the colored squares are way too big and not formatted correctly. If you open up in IE or other browser the formatting is correct.

```css
.image__container {
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 right: 30px;
}

.section__coloured-image-one {

 width: 70%;
}


.section__coloured-image-two {
 position: absolute;
 width: 70%;
 transform: translate(-90%, 10%);
}

.section__coloured-image-three {
 position: absolute;
 width: 50%;
 transform: translate(-106%, 235%);

}
```

```html
<div class="index__section-two__div-left">
    
     <div  class="image__container">
      <img  class="section__coloured-image-one" src="https://upsites.co.za/images/Rectangle 15.png">
      <img  class="section__coloured-image-two" src="https://upsites.co.za/images/Rectangle 15.png">
      <img  class="section__coloured-image-three" src="https://upsites.co.za/images/Asset 1.png">
     </div>
     
    
   </div>
```

I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: welcome to SO @Gavin, it will be easy to solve your problem you you can post the screenshot of the output of your code in chrome and IE.

Comment: Your certification is invalid.